# How to debug config variable in Snakefile

Tags: debugging, snakemake

I'm trying to understand a complicated Snakemake workflow with multiple config and profile layers.

In the Snakefile, a variable `config` is referenced that is not imported, the first few lines are as follows:

```py
import datetime

if "builds" not in config:
    config["builds"] = {}
```

Where will this `config` variable come from at runtime? Can I debug the Snakefile how I would debug a normal Python script to make Snakemake stop at a break point, allowing me to inspect variables?

Note: The flag `--verbose` helps by including stack traces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `config` python dictionary is a special variable that can be populated in three ways:

- using the keyword "configfile" directly in the Snakefile will import all keys/values from a json or yaml file in the python dict `config`:

```
configfile: "myConfig.json"
```

- from the command line by specifying a json or yaml file which will import all key/value pairs in the python dict `config`:

```
snakemake --configfile myconfig.json ...
```

- from the command line by specifying a (or multiple) key/value pair(s):

```
snakemake --config builds="mybuilds" ...
```

In your case, my guess is that the user of the snakemake pipeline is supposed to provide a configuration file on the command line. Don't forget that all python code outside the rules is executed first so you can debug any bad configuration before any rule is executed.

Comment: Thanks! What's a good way to debug the python code that's executed before rules?
There are some constructs in the Snakefile that do not look like normal Python and will probably be processed by Snakemake in some internal way.

Comment: Snakemake has to know all the process it will go through before starting to execute the rules. You can always launch a dry run (`-n` argument) and print the shell commands (`-p` argument) to check that everything's ok before running the pipeline for real. As for the python code to be run before the rules, do it like you would do it for any python program.